# Number of outlook tasks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks, to-do

I have 2 overdue tasks at work in outlook desktop, 4 in To Do desktop, and 5 in To Do online. I've tried logging off and back on, and clearing out the sync issues. How can I get them to sync up?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the method mentioned in this official document and see if it could help solve your issue.
[Plan and connect in Microsoft To Do](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/plan-and-connect-in-microsoft-to-do-f64171ef-f550-4151-bae3-492720f3f1aa).